# $k$-witness of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Today I saw a definition of k-witness of a graph, which is defined as follows (or see section 3 from the article  https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/17M1133051).

For a graph $G$ of order $n$, a $k$-witness (or a witness of order
$k$) in $G$ is a pair of ordered vertex $k$-tuples
$\left(\left(s_{i}\right)_{i \in[k]},\left(t_{i}\right)_{i
\in[k]}\right)$ such that $s_{i}, t_{i} \in V(G), s_{i} \sim t_{i}$
for each $i$, and $s_{i} \nsim t_{j}$ for $i<j$.
The definition requires $s_{i} \neq s_{j}$ and $t_{i} \neq
t_{j}$ for $i \neq j$, but it might happen that $s_{i}=t_{j}$ for
some $i>j$.

I still don't know enough about the above definition, maybe my question is a little simple, whether it means that for a complete bipartite graph $K_{s,t}$, where $s>t$, should be $t$-witness?

Similarly I would like to know if there is some regularity for $r$-regular graphs to find such $k$-witness?

Thanks all of you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will pay attention to getting rid of this bad habit.

Comment: Where did you see this definition? Having a source with context might help someone explain what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and suggestion, I have added to the question.